# Exception in starting filter - Servlet

Tags: java, xml, servlets, filter, classnotfoundexception

I've correctly definited the filter class in xml file, but everytime i start the servlet, it would throw a error as can't start filter. When i see in logs, it states java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

My xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>userLogin</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UserAction</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userLogin</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/userLogin</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>userRegistration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UserAction</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>userRegistration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/userRegistration</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>createUser</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>UserAction</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>createUser</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/createUser</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.drona.action.LoginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>loginFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/userLogin</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My Error in catalina logs

```
03-Sep-2014 08:14:40.087 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1]             org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter loginFilter
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/drona/action/LoginFilter (wrong name: LoginFilter)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2479)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:880)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1294)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1177)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:550)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4603)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5210)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1071)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1722)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

03-Sep-2014 08:14:40.627 INFO [localhost-startStop-1]     org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
03-Sep-2014 08:14:40.627 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

I've my filter class LoginFilter in exactly the same folder which i defined in xml (WEB-INF/classes/com/drona/action/LoginFilter) . But I cant figure out why it's. I just have a doubt that does i have to define it as /com/drona/action/LoginFilter in xml file?

Comment: No, the web.xml configuration takes the class name. Double-check that it's really in `WEB-INF/classes` and that there are no typos.

Answer (score 0):

Just I figured out if i put the filter class in classes folder instead of com.drona.action.filterclass, and changing the filter class path to LoginFilter, so it'll call it directly.. But this is not the exact solution, anyhow I'll find it some or other way.. Have to check it on all possible cases..